# Why can't I set the values for the POST variables?

Tags: java, php, android

I'm currently developing an Android app which interacts with a server (Local for now). 
For this I am using PHP to communicate the Java code with the server. 
This is the first time I use PHP so I'm having a hard time with this.

For some reasons all the values i need to save in the database are null, it doesn't matter if I get them from the app or from the URL when i test the PHP code. The only message i get is:

> {"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}.

I tried print_r ($_POST) and i got: Array(), not sure what that means. I also tried everything i saw on internet with no success.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$response = array();


if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['breed']) && !empty($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['description']) && !empty($_POST['images']) && !empty($_POST['coords'])) {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$breed = $_POST['breed'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$images = $_POST['images'];
$coords = $_POST['coords'];


require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';


$db = new DB_CONNECT();


$result = "INSERT INTO lost_pets (name, breed, type, description, images, coords) VALUES(':name', ':breed', ':type', ':description', ':images', ':coords')";

$stmt = $db->prepare($result);

$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':breed', $_POST['breed'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':type', $_POST['type'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->bindParam(':description', $_POST['description'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':images', $_POST['images'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':coords', $_POST['coords'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute(); 


if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";


    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";


    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";


echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I am pretty sure the problem is in this code, and not in the Java code. I hope you can help me here, thanks!

Comment: Try get the error and post here.

Comment: You can use postman to check if the server response is correct or not

Comment: `I tried print_r ($_POST) and i got: Array(), not sure what that means.`. It means that the $_POST array is empty.

Comment: If your $_POST is empty that sounds like something to do with your HTML forms being passed... can you show your HTML/JQuery  form snippet?

Comment: looks like the problem is with your android app. It isn't posting anything to the server. if any post data was received from the app, the $_POST variable would be populated and you wouldn't get `Array()` when running `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: @Dis-Mag If i set the values in the URL, i get the same 'error'

Comment: @PaulaDaniela in the url it's `$_GET` that gets populated and not `$_POST`. I think that is the problem. Try changing all where you used `$_POST` to `$_GET` and see in the error is not solved. PHP also has a $_REQUEST variable which catches both `$_GET` and `$_POST` data. I hope you understand the difference between GET & POST form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly assigning your SQL query string to the `$result` variable, then blithely testing the query string itself for success.

Use `$query` for your query string, and test `$stmt->execute()` for failure instead:

```
if ($stmt->execute() === FALSE) {
    // ERROR
}
else {
    // Success!
}
```

Comment: Now, i'm getting this: Call to undefined method DB_CONNECT::prepare()

Comment: I found the mistake, i forgot to instantiate the connect method inside DB_CONNECT, which returned the connection. Your code worked perfectly. Thank you very very much!